# Stored Procedures calls two other stored procedures, but only 1 seems to run. No error thrown

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, stored-procedures, dynamic

### Problem:

Hi I've got two stored procedures, that I try to run from another one.
- If I call them one after the other from phpmysqladmin, everything works fine.
- If I call the stored procedure, that calls the other two, I don't get an error. So far so good. But the problem is, that the operations from the second stored procedure aren't executed.

### Already tried to run it in just one sp...

I also tried to run both stored procedures (sp1,sp2) in one stored procedure, with the same effect.

### Could that be the problem?

In the first sp I use a statement like this:

```
Select @var:= ....
```

### Here is the code:

In the first stored procedure I generate a dynamic query and execute it.

### Procedure 1

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_prepare_valid_choices`(IN p_request_id Bigint)
BEGIN
  DECLARE num_rows INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE no_more_rows BINARY;
  DECLARE no_more_subrows BINARY;
  DECLARE loop_cntr INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE var_choice_group BIGINT DEFAULT 0;

-- Declare Cursor for the loop through the constraint_groups
  DECLARE cur_constraint_group CURSOR FOR     
  SELECT distinct choice_constraint_group FROM casainte_choice_constraint
    WHERE choice_id_rule_parameter IN (SELECT choice_id FROM casainte_request_detail
                                        where request_id = p_request_id);
-- DECLARE 'handlers' for exceptions
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
  SET no_more_rows := TRUE;

-- DELETE OLD VALUES
  DELETE FROM tmp_casainte_valid_choices
  WHERE request_id = p_request_id;
  DELETE FROM tmp_casainte_valid_choices_for_request
  WHERE request_id = p_request_id;

-- OPEN CURSOR AN PROCESS CONSTRAINT_GROUPS
  OPEN cur_constraint_group;
  SELECT FOUND_ROWS() INTO num_rows;

  choice_group_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur_constraint_group
    INTO var_choice_group;

  IF no_more_rows THEN
    CLOSE cur_constraint_group;
    LEAVE choice_group_loop;
  END IF;
-- PAYLOAD
 -- INSERT THE VALID CHOCIES INTO tmp_casainte_valid_choices 
 SELECT @var_sql_query := CONCAT('INSERT INTO tmp_casainte_valid_choices ','SELECT ',p_request_id,' as request_id,  `casainte_choice_constraint`.`choice_constraint_id`,`casainte_choice_constraint`.`choice_constraint_group`
    ,AVG(IF (`casainte_request_detail`.`choice_varchar_value`', `casainte_choice_constraint`.`choice_constraint_operator`, '\'',`casainte_choice_constraint`.`choice_constraint_value`, '\'',',1,0 )) AS VALID
FROM `casainte_choice_constraint`
LEFT JOIN `casainte_request_detail` ON `casainte_request_detail`.`choice_id` = `casainte_choice_constraint`.`choice_id_rule_parameter`
WHERE `casainte_choice_constraint`.choice_constraint_group =' , var_choice_group,
' GROUP BY `casainte_choice_constraint`.choice_constraint_group')
FROM `casainte_choice_constraint` WHERE `casainte_choice_constraint`.choice_constraint_group = var_choice_group;
PREPARE SQL_STATEMENT FROM @var_sql_query;
EXECUTE SQL_STATEMENT;
-- INCREMENT THE COUNTER
SET loop_cntr = loop_cntr + 1;

END LOOP choice_group_loop;



END$$
```

### Procedure 2

In the second stored procedure I insert the values into a table.

```
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_insert_valid_choices`(IN p_request_id Bigint)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO tmp_casainte_valid_choices_for_request
(request_id, choice_id)
SELECT DISTINCT p_request_id, choice_id FROM casainte_choice ac
-- RULE 1 ALL CHOICES WITHOUT CONSTRAINTS
WHERE ac.choice_id NOT IN (SELECT choice_id_rule_target FROM casainte_choice_constraint)
-- RULE 2 ALL CHOICES WITH CONSTRAINTS, THAT ARE NOT YET ANSWERED
OR ac.choice_id NOT IN (SELECT choice_id_rule_target FROM casainte_choice_constraint
WHERE choice_id_rule_parameter IN (SELECT choice_id FROM casainte_request_detail WHERE request_id = p_request_id))
-- RULE 3 ALL CHOICES WITH CONSTRAINTS, THAT ARE TRUE
OR ac.choice_id IN (SELECT choice_id_rule_target FROM casainte_choice_constraint
WHERE choice_constraint_group IN (SELECT choice_constraint_group FROM tmp_casainte_valid_choices WHERE request_id = p_request_id AND VALID = 1));
END$$
```

### Procedure 3

The third stored procedure calls the 1st sp, then the 2nd sp.

```
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_generate_valid_choices`(IN p_request_id Bigint)
BEGIN
Call `sp_prepare_valid_choices`(p_request_id);
Call `sp_insert_valid_choices`(p_request_id);
END$$
```

Comment: I removed the reference to `mssql` in the title, since a) tags exist to specify relevant products, etc, and b) mssql tends to be used to refer to Microsoft's SQL Server, which isn't what this question is about.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm sorry, my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have "delimiter $$" at the top of Procedure 1.  Could this be causing the problem?